# Traversing a rose tree with Data.Tree.Zipper

Tags: haskell, tree

I have a rose tree structure that I'm representing with Data.Tree. Each node in the tree is labeled with an (x,y) coordinate. I need to implement a way of finding the node in the tree that is nearest to a given query coordinate and adding a child to that node.

I envision dividing this into two operations:

1. traverse the tree to find the node that is nearest to a given query coordinate
2. take the node found in the prior traversal and add to it a child labeled with the above query coordinate

The only way I can think of doing this is to traverse the tree in step 1 using Data.Tree.Zipper, and then using that zipper in step 2 to insert a node in a specific location.

I have two questions:

- Is this an effective way to approach the problem?
- If so, how do I use the functions in Data.Tree.Zipper to implement step 1 above? I'm finding the tree traversal difficult to implement because it requires recursion in two dimensions: depth and breadth.

Comment: Tell us more about step 1. Is the tree organized in any way?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, there isn't any ordering of children or relevant relation between parents and children. I'm satisfied with performing a full tree traversal to search for the nearest node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can implement step 1 without assuming anything about the layout of a tree. For simplicity, I'm going to pick out the minimal node, rather than the node that minimizes some function, but it's not hard to modify this idea. For some reason, `rosezipper` doesn't offer an operation to get all the children of a zipper, so we have to implement that first. Once we've done that, the idea is pretty simple: recurse on the children, then pick the minimum of either the current location or the results of the recursion.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import Data.Tree
import Data.Tree.Zipper

childrenAsList :: TreePos Full a -> [TreePos Full a]
childrenAsList = go . children where
    go z = case nextTree z of
        Nothing -> []
        Just z  -> z : go (nextSpace z)

minZipper :: Ord a => Tree a -> TreePos Full a
minZipper = go . fromTree where
    go z = minimumBy (comparing (rootLabel . tree))
                     (z:map go (childrenAsList z))
```

You certainly don't need to use a zipper to do something efficient, but it is certainly one reasonable and good way to approach the problem. One advantage of this approach compared to the two-traversal approach is that it should have maximal sharing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need zippers to do simple tree traversals.

```
import Data.Foldable (minimumBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Tree

addPt :: (Eq a, Ord b) => (a -> a -> b) -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a
addPt dist p t = down t
  where
    down (Node a xs)
      | a == closest = Node a (Node p []:xs)
      | otherwise    = Node a (map down xs)
    closest = minimumBy (compare `on` dist p) t
```

This will add the point multiple times if the closest point as returned by `minimumBy` is duplicated, and could be made slightly more efficient since `down` always traverses the tree fully, even if it finds the element early.  To fix both issues, you could write a function that explores each branch in turn, returning the (possibly augmented) branch plus, say, a `Bool` to indicate whether the point was added.  On the other hand, `addPt` is naturally highly parallelizable (modulo the use of linked lists in Data.Tree, and replacing `minimumBy` by a parallel version) and this is lost if you try to save work by sequentializing it.  Using a zipper could certainly be somewhat more efficient in the sequential case.

Comment: This is great! This definitely works, but do you know if there is a way to do this in one tree traversal? In this case, one traversal is required to find the closest node, and then another traversal is done to "re-find" that closest node. I'll probably end up implementing your solution, but I'm curious if there's an idiomatic way to do it in one traversal, even if it's complicated.

Comment: I'm certain some zipper- or continuation-based solution would work.

Comment: I'm super confused by this advice. What makes this better than using a zipper? It looks like it would have awful performance in comparison.

Comment: Sorry about the unaccept Fixnum; Daniel's comment motivated me to leave the question open so that others might be more willing to share their own solutions for this.

Comment: I didn't intend to claim this was "better", and in fact pointed out the performance caveats.  "You don't need zippers" was in response to "the only way I can think of...".